# How to push down a <div> after duplicating another <div>?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't know if my title can be understood clearly but what I'm aiming for is after I click a button, the div on top of the button will be duplicated directly below the original so the button will have to go down. I read about using position: absolute and position: relative but it seems that it does not work.

```
document.getElementById('parentDIV').style.position = 'relative';
document.getElementById('duplicetor1').style.position = 'absolute';
document.getElementById('buttons').style.position = 'absolute';
document.getElementById('duplicetor1').style.zIndex = '2';
```

The code above shows how I used JS to change the style of each div. This is the link to my whole code https://jsfiddle.net/rickiestrick/9cpbs0hm/4/.

Comment: Please include a [mre] in the question here on Stack Overflow, not only on an external site. You can use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar), which provides and interface much like jsFiddle.

Comment: Seems like your problem can be fixed in a easier way.
Maybe you should use Insertbefore(mybutton), instead of adding the rooms below the button. This way you don't need some CSS tricks..

EDIT:
insertBefore(newRoom,buttonsDiv);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to "play" with positionig. Just place the cloned element before the buttons block.

Here an example of your duplicate function

```
function duplicate() {
  var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
  var btns = document.querySelector('.buttons-room');
  clone.id = "duplicetor" + ++i;
  original.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, btns);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not try with `position: absolute` it will be messy. I suggest you to set position of your button with margin and other stuff. After that instead of adding duplicated div at the end of the parent div(line 74 of your code), append that div after the original div with this syntax:

```
original.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, original.nextSibling);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Your Button Hierarchy in HTML and don't use absolute

Here is the minified version

HTML

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="label-bar">
          <h2>Choose the perfect room for you!</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="inner-content-wrapper" id=parentDIV>
          <div class="room" id="duplicater">
            <select id="sel">
              <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Pick room type</option>
              <option value="1">Single Room (1 Adult)</option>
              <option value="2">Double Room (2 Adults)</option>
              <option value="2">Family Room (4 Adults)</option>
            </select>
            <div class="additionalPerson">
              <input type="checkbox" id="additional-person" name="scales" class="largerCheckbox">
              <label for="additional-person">Add an additional person</label>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
        
          <div class="buttons-room" id="buttons">
            <button onlick="addRoom()" class="btn add" id="button1">Add another room</button>
      
            <button class="btn check">Check availability</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('button1').onclick = duplicate;

              var i = 0;
              var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');

              function duplicate() {
                var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
                clone.id = "duplicetor" + ++i;
                original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);

                document.getElementById('parentDIV').style.position = 'relative';
                document.getElementById('duplicetor1').style.position = 'relative';
                document.getElementById('buttons').style.position = 'relative';
                document.getElementById('duplicetor1').style.zIndex = '2';
              }
```